# didn't get value in post which was set by jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="trim_video_form" id="trim_video_form" action="video_ajax.php?v=54f85644" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="crop_video">

            <div class="trim_video_outr">
                <!--<iframe src="embed.php?v=54f85644&statTrack=&w=512&h=288&iframe=1&trimmingType=video" width="512" height="288" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="trim_video_popup_iframe"></iframe>-->
                <iframe src="http://easyweb.site/embed.php?v=54f85644&amp;statTrack=&amp;w=512&amp;h=288&amp;iframe=1&amp;trimmingType=video" width="591" height="335" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="trim_video_popup_iframe"></iframe>

            </div>

            <div class="show_time_row">

                From : &nbsp;<input type="text" name="start_time_show" style="width:60px;" class="start_time_show show_time_input">

                <input type="hidden" name="start_time" style="width:60px;" class="start_time" value="Left-Flag">&nbsp; 

                To : &nbsp;<input type="text" name="end_time_show" style="width:60px;" class="end_time_show show_time_input">

                <input type="hidden" name="end_time" style="width:60px;" class="end_time" value="24.24641666666667"> &nbsp; Seconds

            </div>

            <div style="margin:14px 0; color:#676767;">

                <input type="radio" name="save_new" class="save_new" value="1" checked="checked"> Save As New Video

                <input type="radio" name="save_new" class="save_new" value="0" style="margin-left:15px;"> Overwrite Original<br>

            </div>

            <div class="trim_video_title">Video Title : &nbsp; <input type="text" name="video_title" value="" class="video_title_input trim_title"><br><br></div>

            <input type="button" name="upload" id="trim_image_btn" value="Trim Video" class="blackbtn">
        </form>
        <input type="hidden" value="">
        <input type="submit" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

js code

```
function trimVideo(startTime, endTime)
{
    $('.start_time').val(startTime);
    $('.end_time').val(endTime);
    var startTime = secondsToHms(startTime);
    var endTime = secondsToHms(endTime);
    $('.start_time_show').val(startTime);
    $('.end_time_show').val(endTime);
}
```

php code

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "crop_video") { echo '<pre>';var_dump($_POST);die('in ajax');}
```

js function is called on change in value. 
this php code is called in an ajax method.

I can see the value attribute added with it's value to the input field.
I am setting input value by using jQuery. Browser shows the value. But when I submit it using POST the in php file POST shows input value empty. why

Comment: would you please update your full code, this stuff is not sufficient to give your answer, update with jquare and php code

Comment: input type hidden and value is decleared with empty how you expect some data???

Comment: this is html not jquery and very badly written html @AsifUddin yes also saw that lol

Comment: yes this tooo much ;) loll @Gert

Answer (score 3):

I believe that is because you missing attribute `name`

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="someProperty" value="">
```

PHP

```
<?php echo $_POST['someProperty']; ?>
```

Comment: may be possible but without his full code you can not say that this is a problem

Comment: that will get you no value either because value is still value=""

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there was a code which overwrites the value submitted on POST. that is why POST parameter becomes empty on receiving. There was no error in this code.